# Custom Code Generation in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, code-generation

How can I generate C# code from an XML file at compile time? Is there even a way to do this? Below is an example of my XML:

```
<Resources xmlns="" Version="1.0">
    <Language Culture="Neutral">
        <Group Name="Default">
            <Resource Name="File"><![CDATA[File]]></Resource>
        </Group>
        <Group Name="Files">
            <Resource Name="Title"><![CDATA[[~Default.File] Selector]]></Resource>
            <Resource Name="SearchLabel"><![CDATA[Enter Search]]></Resource>
        </Group>
    </Language>
</Resources>
```

This is a string resource collection. As you can see, it is self referencing, which RESX is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into T4 templates. T4 templates are a feature of Visual Studio that allow you transform arbitrary files into code during a build.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

Comment: I know what T4 templates are. They don't provide compile time code regen, do they?

Comment: There, I undeleted my answer. I wasn't sure what you meant by "compile-time generation" and I'm still not sure. I know that T4 templates regenerate when you save the input file. I don't know if they regenerate on build if the output file doesn't already exist.

Comment: Oh, see I didn't know that. I thought they were little more than an extensibility on top of the Visual Studio project and item templates. You shouldn't delete your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a look at [T4 (Text Template Transformation Toolkit)](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/) would be of interest for you. Whenever there is a need for generating data or code it should be a good bet.

Comment: Someone already suggested this and deleted their question. I wish they hadn't because I am aware of T4, but I don't think that T4 supports compile-time code generation, I could be wrong.

Comment: T4 is well-suited for code-generation at compile time, see e.g. Scott Hanselmans great old post [T4 (Text Template Transformation Toolkit) Code Generation - Best Kept Visual Studio Secret](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use XSLT in a pre-build step to convert your XML into compilable code.

Comment: I usually avoid XSLT like its the plague, but what exactly do you mean? Also, XSLT would not support the self referencing feature in my XML very well.

Comment: XSLT is a good choice for transforming XML to another format, e.g. to C#. With a little work, it should be able to handle the self-referencing okay. You can get Visual Studio to execute arbitrary commands at the start of a build, one of which could be the transformation of your XML to some other format via an XSLT processor.